# Why don't I get output when I use __DATA__ in Perl?

Tags: perl, macos-catalina

Does anybody know if the Perl `__DATA__` syntax on macOS Catalina is deprecated? I have perl v5.18.4 running, even a simple program like this gives no output (and no error either);

```
use strict;
use warnings;
while(<DATA>){
    print $_;
}

__DATA__
line1
line2
line3
```

**Edit**:
This is weird. I said earlier that I have 2 Mac systems, both having the same problem. Not quite right, on one system the program works, on the other system the same program doesn’t.

Hexdump on both systems is the same:

Mac Mini:

```
Mac-mini-van-Theo:Programming theo$ hexdump -C test.pl
00000000  75 73 65 20 73 74 72 69  63 74 3b 0d 75 73 65 20  |use strict;.use |
00000010  77 61 72 6e 69 6e 67 73  3b 0d 77 68 69 6c 65 28  |warnings;.while(|
00000020  3c 44 41 54 41 3e 29 20  7b 0d 20 20 20 20 70 72  |<DATA>) {.    pr|
00000030  69 6e 74 20 24 5f 3b 0d  7d 0d 5f 5f 44 41 54 41  |int $_;.}.__DATA|
00000040  5f 5f 0d 6c 69 6e 65 31  0d 6c 69 6e 65 32 0d 6c  |__.line1.line2.l|
00000050  69 6e 65 33 0d                                    |ine3.|
00000055
```

iMac:

```
Theo@iMac-van-Theo Programming % hexdump -C test.pl
00000000  75 73 65 20 73 74 72 69  63 74 3b 0a 75 73 65 20  |use strict;.use |
00000010  77 61 72 6e 69 6e 67 73  3b 0a 77 68 69 6c 65 28  |warnings;.while(|
00000020  3c 44 41 54 41 3e 29 7b  0a 20 20 20 20 70 72 69  |<DATA>){.    pri|
00000030  6e 74 20 24 5f 3b 0a 7d  0a 0a 5f 5f 44 41 54 41  |nt $_;.}..__DATA|
00000040  5f 5f 0a 6c 69 6e 65 31  0a 6c 69 6e 65 32 0a 6c  |__.line1.line2.l|
00000050  69 6e 65 33 0a                                    |ine3.|
00000055
```

However, a 'cat’ or a ‘more’ shows differences:

Mac Mini:

```
Mac-mini-van-Theo:Programming theo$ more test.pl
use strict;^Muse warnings;^Mwhile(<DATA>) {^M    print $_;^M}^M__DATA__^Mline1^Mline2^Mline3
```

iMac:

```
Theo@iMac-van-Theo Programming % more test.pl 
use strict;
use warnings;
while(<DATA>){
    print $_;
}

__DATA__
line1
line2
line3
```

The difference? The Mac Mini uses ‘bash’ as shell (where the program fails), the iMac uses ‘zsh’. So the problem is not really perl related but perl/shell related. With Catalina, Zsh is used as the default shell but the old Bash shell is still included with macOS and you can still switch to it. It seems to be related to how the shell handles line-endings, although I do not understand why this happens and moreover how to solve it.

Comment: At least in my environment (macOS Big Sur, perl v5.28.3), your code is ok, with no problem.

Comment: Check your line endings?

Comment: Try printing some output before and after reading DATA, to see whether its just the data handle that's the issue.

Comment: That sure looks like a line-endings problem. I use bash on the mac and don't have this problem,.

Comment: Please inspect your hexdump once more - in one case eol is 0d (13)<CR> and in other 0a (10) <LF>.

Answer (score 8):

`__DATA__` is just fine, and there's no platform-specific issues with it (and there are lots of [stupid tricks](https://www.perl.com/article/stupid-data-tricks/) you can do with it).

However, if you want to know the state of any particular Perl thing, there's the [perldeprecation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldeprecation) docs. Sometimes [perlexperiment](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlexperiment) is handy too.

How are you running your program?

Supply a hexdump of your program: `hexdump -C program.pl`. Maybe there are funny characters.

Comment: Non blocking exclusive flock on DATA to ensure single script instance (just read tricks article).

Comment: Lineendings are OK. There are no whitespaces or CR's before and after \_\_DATA\_\_. I run the test program via Terminal. I have 2 Mac systems, both running Catalina with perl v5.18.4. They both have the same problem. Other perl programs are running fine, it is just the issue with \_\_DATA\_\_ and I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Update your question with any clarifications